# How would I go about installing Windows 8?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, reinstalling

I purchased this laptop a year or so ago and immediately switched to Ubuntu since it was faster and did everything that I needed it for faster.

Except now I would like to dual boot, but can't figure how to hell to run a program to install Windows 8 on a different partition. I don't have the code itself (it's tied to the motherboard), and MS has removed the option for a bootable Win 8 disk. Every other executable I've found (even trying to get Win7 through less than proper means) doesn't work on Ubuntu.

Comment: We support questions regarding Ubuntu; this is about installing Windows. "Every other executable I've found (even trying to get Win7 through less than proper means) doesn't work on Ubuntu." Of course those do not work. A Linux executable also does not work on Windows. To install Windows you need a Windows installation disk. If you do not have one you need to buy Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recovery disk that came with your laptop, you should be able to boot from it by hitting F12 when your laptop first boots, and choose it as a boot device, and then from there, install windows. 
If you have an iso for a windows installation, then you can burn that to a disk, or a USB, (instructions can be found here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) and then choose that at boot. I've never installed windows, but I assume you can choose a partition to install it on.

After you install windows, you will likely need to use boot-repair to allow dual-boot (http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) and burn this to a usb or CD as well, boot from it preferably legacy boot since it allows you a nice GUI to edit settings, and run boot-repair off the desktop if it doesn't start automatically, use the recommended fix and after that finishes, reboot and allow ubuntu to boot, and there should be a new menu with Ubuntu at the top and your windows installation at the bottom.

Issues: If your screen goes black after running boot-repair, its likely you need to have nomodeset on, which can be done while booting. Hit f6 and navigate to nomodeset and hit enter. Then hit escape and try booting.

EDIT: If you have any questions, issues, or want me to go into further detail on some of the steps, let me know. I might just give you a link where the steps or issues are explained much better than I could explain them